# Problems parsing a web page in python

Tags: python, html, lxml, html5lib

I would like to parse a web page in order to retrieve some information about it (my exact problem is to retrieve all the items in this list : http://www.computerhope.com/vdef.htm).

However, I can't figure out how to do it.

A lot of tutorials on the internet start with this (simplified) :
`html5lib.parse(urlopen("http://www.computerhope.com/vdef.htm"))`

But after that, none of the tutorials explain how I can browse the document and go the html part I am looking for.

Some other tutorials explain how to do it with `CSSSelector` but again, all the tutorials don't start with a web page but with a string instead (e.g. here : http://lxml.de/cssselect.html).

So I tried to create a tree with the web page using this : 
`fromstring(urlopen("http://www.computerhope.com/vdef.htm").read())`
but I got this error :
`lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Specification mandate value for attribute itemscope, line 3, column 28`. This error is due to the fact that there is an attribute that is not specified (e.g. `<input attribute></input>`) but as I don't control the webpage, I can't go around it.

So here are a few questions that could solve my problems :

- How can I browse a tree ?
- Is there a way to make the parser less strict ?

Thank you !

Comment: Look for XPath. It is very powerful tool to parse any XML-like structure.

Comment: Why are you using etree to parse html?

Answer (score 2):

Try using beautiful soup, it has some excellent features and makes parsing in Python extremely easy.

Check of their documentation at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.computerhope.com/vdef.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)
tables = soup.findChildren('table')
for i in (tables[0].findAll('a')):
    print(i.text)
```

It prints out all the items in the list, I hope the OP Will make adjustments accordingly.

Comment: Can I know why the down vote?? If you do not like the library that does not mean my answer is wrong, that just means our opinions differ.

Comment: I did not downvote but I guess that you got the downvote because this is a link-only answer with no details that actually answer the question..